# Edible Mushrooms

Tags: mushrooms

Does anyone know if these mushrooms, that are growing in my back yard, (see picture) are edible?

[image: photo of mushrooms]

Comment: I'm fairly certain that *no one* is going to be responsible for answering that question in the affirmative.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mycology.  Culinary practice starts after it is harvested and in the kitchen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a [handful of distinctive mushrooms](http://livingafield.com/Mushrooms.htm) that are usually safe to pick, even for a layman. This ain't one of them. This looks quite a lot like a member of the *Amanitaceae* family (shaped like an umbrella, with white "gills"), and people tend to avoid those because they all look similar, and some of them can kill you.

If you don't know for certain what they are, don't eat them.